# A shorter way to transform enumValues to a multi-value map

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin. I was thinking if there is a shorter way to write the following piece of code. It means to categorize enum values into a multi-value map.

```
fun androidPermissionsByCategory(): Map<String, List<String>> {
    val result = hashMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
    enumValues<AndroidPermission>().onEach {
        result.getOrPut(it.permissionGroup, { mutableListOf() }).add(it.value())
    }
    return result
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's good, solid code (especially if you're not experienced in Kotlin): good use of types, and the `getOrPut()` function.  (The only tweak I'd suggest would be to change `hashMapOf()` to `mutableMapOf()`, since you don't care about the exact type of map.  You could also replace the `add()` call with `+=` operator, though that's more disputable.)

However, there's a shorter alternative in a more functional style:

```
fun androidPermissionsByCategory(): Map<String, List<String>>
    = enumValues<AndroidPermission>()
        .groupBy({ it.permissionGroup }, { it.value() })
```

<sub>(Disclaimer: I don't have Android libs, so I can't test this exactly.)</sub>

This uses the standard library's [`groupBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) function, which does exactly what you want: it compares items (using a key-selector lambda you provide), and uses it to create a multimap from them.

Here we're using the enum's `permissionGroup` field as the key.

We're also using the optional second parameter to transform the values in the multimap, in this case getting their `value()`.

You'll find that Kotlin has functional alternatives to many of the common imperative patterns for constructing and transforming maps, lists, and similar structures; these are often more concise, more declarative, and easier to read.  Any time you find yourself looping over a list or similar, it's worth asking whether there's a better way.  (As you have here!  Your intuition is clearly working well :-)

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!